# Pairing Adjacent Values in a Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Say I have an array of values `array = [0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0]`, and I want to pair adjacent values into a secondary list `paired_array = [[0.0, 0.2], [0.2, 0.5], [0.5, 0.8], [0.8, 1.0]]`, is there an easy way of doing that in numpy?

For context, the pairs represent probability ranges which I will be using to randomise the values in a numpy array of type string. For example `string_array = ['Fe', 'Pt', 'Fe', 'Pt', 'Fe', 'Pt', 'Fe', 'Pt']` may become something like `randomised_array = ['Pt', 'Fe', 'Pt', 'Pt', 'Pt', 'Pt', 'Fe', 'Fe']`. The ranges represent the probability a value is 'Pt' or 'Fe' in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRY:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view 

array = [0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0]
result = sliding_window_view(array, 2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([[0. , 0.2],
       [0.2, 0.5],
       [0.5, 0.8],
       [0.8, 1. ]])
```